# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `time_format`. All arguments must be numeric or NA

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I have the code below for both R script as well as R shiny.When the code is executed in R script,it doesn't throw any error but when the same code is executed in R shiny,it throws the error as highlighted:

```
Error: Problem with mutate() input time_format.
x All arguments must be numeric or NA
i Input time_format is hms(promax_2020_data$Time) %>% as.duration().
```

promax_2020_data_time is a dataframe.Time column is of char type.

R script:-

```
promax_Jan_Sep_2020_data<-read.csv("Promax_Jan_Sept_2020_Data.csv")

promax_Oct_Dec_2020_data<-read.csv("Promax_Oct_Dec_2020_Data.csv")

promax_2020_data<-rbind(promax_Jan_Sep_2020_data,promax_Oct_Dec_2020_data)

promax_2020_data_time <- mutate(promax_2020_data,
                                time_format = hms(promax_2020_data$Time) %>% as.duration())


R shiny:-

#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#


promax_Jan_Sep_2020_data<-read.csv("Promax_Jan_Sept_2020_Data.csv")

promax_Oct_Dec_2020_data<-read.csv("Promax_Oct_Dec_2020_Data.csv")

promax_2020_data<-rbind(promax_Jan_Sep_2020_data,promax_Oct_Dec_2020_data)


promax_2020_data_time <- mutate(promax_2020_data,
                                time_format = hms(promax_2020_data$Time) %>% as.duration())
```

I have tried using hms and lubridate packages in R shiny too but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Could you reduce the problem you're encountering to a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sometimes problems like this are related to the data input. As Waldi pointed out, please use MRE, and take everything out that isn't necessary to reproduce your error. Provide a small dataset using `dput()`.

Comment: @Waldi I have reduced the code to relevant pieces of requirement and need.Hope this helps.